# Lookup field not appearing in process builder

Tags: formula, process-builder, lookup

[image]I am trying to write a process builder on Standard Case Object. Now, the standard case object has a lookup to a custom object obj. I am trying to update a field of case with the value of an email field of obj. However when I am looking for the obj object related to case it is not showing up in the dropdown. Can anyone tell me where am I making a mistake

The Case Object has a lookup to Contractor,

Comment: can you post a picture of process builder configuration

Comment: This post doesn't really contain enough detail to help you. Perhaps a screenshot would be helpful in this case.

Comment: Are your field security settings correct for that field?

Comment: That was it. Thanks @EricSSH. Please put in in the answer section so that I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As above per my comment above..

Make sure your field security settings are correct!